# What are the properties of the unidentified elements, Θ Ω Σ and Δ?

Tags: spacechem

The last few levels of SpaceChem introduces you to a number of 'unidentified elements', contained in an errata to your Periodic Table, labeled with the Greek characters Θ Ω Σ and Δ, or, Theta, Omega, Sigma and Delta. The Table contains no information on these elements - they have **?** atomic number, and are allowed **?** number of  maximum bonds - other than the fact that they exist, and will be used in reactions.

What are the actual properties of these elements that we can tease out using the reactors? What will happen when we try to fuse, bond and split these elements?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A Fission laser produces these results when fed the extra atoms in the ResearchNet sandbox mode.

**Θ** → **Fm** 100 x2
**Ω** → **Md** 101 + **Fm** 100
**Σ** → **Md** 101 x2
**Δ** → **Md** 101 + No 102

This implies that the elements have the following atomic numbers:

**Θ** - 200
**Ω** - 201
**Σ** - 202
**Δ** - 203

Although I have not tested it, I imagine that fusing them would be like trying to fuse any other combination that does not produce a valid element, nothing happens. Also note that attempting to fuse **Fm** and **Fm** together into **Θ** does not work. The same is likely the case for the others.

A quick experiment in the puzzle generator reveals that they can accept twelve bonds, which is three in each direction, the maximum possible number.

I tested all this using the ResearchNet user generated puzzle system, which allows much greater flexibility in setting up testing scenarios.